# How does Windows 8 app update mechanism deal with existing files in ApplicationData.LocalFolder?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm about to publish an update to my Win8 app.

How does the Win8 app store handle updates? Will the application data folder be kept intact when a new version is installed?
How does ApplicationData.SetVersionAsync() affect this?

Will there be seperate sub-folders for each version?

I need to make sure all the user's data is brought forward to the new version of my app. I'll take care of data file formats - but I just need to know how the folders will be handled by the update mechanism.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer!

http://t.co/rIUFkpgv

I found that article on MSDN about app data, which says:

> ...The system also preserves the contents of these data stores when the user installs an update to your app ...

So basically, app data stays in the same place - and the new version can simply read the old files and decide what to do!